# Query is working on phpmyadmin but not in express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, postman

I have a problem with a MySQL query, I'm making a controller where  I need a filter on the front (React). The controller is made with params inside the route, but is not working when I try to test it with Postman, but if I make the same exact query on phpmyadmin works perfectly.

Controller:

```
let { tabla, nameUno, fechaIni, fechaFin, nameDos, nameTres, nameCuatro } =
      req.params;
    conn.query(
      // SELECT * FROM tyt_finan WHERE tf_fecha_r BETWEEN '2022-05-31' AND '2022-06-01' AND tf_city IN ('Bogota') AND tf_estado = 'Pendiente' AND tf_campana = 'IN'
      "SELECT * FROM " +
        tabla +
        " WHERE " +
        nameUno +
        " BETWEEN " +
        fechaIni +
        " AND " +
        fechaFin +
        " AND " +
        nameDos +
        " IN ('') AND " +
        nameTres +
        " = ? AND " +
        nameCuatro +
        " = ?",
      [req.params.value1, req.params.value2, req.params.value3],
```

Routes

```
routes.get(
  "/searchAll/:tabla/:nameUno/:fechaIni/:fechaFin/:nameDos/:value1/:nameTres/:value2/:nameCuatro/:value3",
  defaultController.searchAll
);
```

And this is the GET petition that I'm sending on Postman:

```
http://localhost:9000/searchAll/tyt_finan/tf_fecha_r/'2022-05-31'/'2022-06-01'/tf_city/'Bogota','Barranquilla'/tf_estado/'Pendiente'/tf_campana/'IN'
```

Comment: You're not putting quotes around `fechaIni` and `fechaFin`. Use `?` parameters instead of concatenating variables, just like you do for `req.params.valueX`.

Comment: Why do you have `IN ('')` instead of `IN ('Bogota')`?

Comment: And if you simply printed out the result of all the concatenation you would have seen the difference.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters for the variables. It's also easier to use a template literal than concatenation to construct the SQL string with variables for the table and column names.

You also had more values in your parameters array than `?` in the SQL. I've replaced `IN ('')` with `= ?` to use `value1` there.

```
let {tabla, nameUno, fechaIni, fechaFin, nameDos, value1, nameTres, value2, nameCuatro, value3} = req.params;
conn.query(
  `SELECT * 
    FROM ${tabla} 
    WHERE ${nameUno} BETWEEN ? AND ? 
        AND ${nameDos} = ?
        AND ${nameTres} = ? 
        AND ${nameCuatro} = ?`, [fetchaIni, fechaFin, value1, value2, value3], (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
```